# Do I have to install .NET on server?

Tags: .net, console-application

I created a Console application, and want it to run on our server. But I get the following message:

To run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .NET Framework: .NETFramework, Version=4.5

Do I really have to install .NET on my server? Can't all necessary stuff be included in the application as a .dll or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can't all necessary stuff be included in the application as a .dll or something?

No.

> Do I really have to install .NET on my server?

Yes you must.

You could of course simply target a version of the framework that is already there - for example, it is entirely possible that .NET 2.0 is already installed, and it is entirely possible that your project will compile for .NET 2.0 without changes (just change the target framework in the project properties).

Comment: _"for example, it is entirely possible that .NET 2.0 is already installed"_ - this. Why is this console app targeting 4.5 anyway?

Comment: @CodeCaster quite possibly: to use 4.5 features. For example, it could be a web-socket server, or make extensive use of async. Console apps can be as sophisticated as you like.

Comment: Even Server 2003 updates come with 4 now don't they? Or 3.5? Can't remember.. but surely the server already has > .NET 2 if it's applied its updates..

Comment: There could very well be that he is using some features from Net 4.5, but for most parts those could be rewritten for 2.0.

Comment: @Marc of course that's possible, but my guess was that it's just some simple commandline tool written using VS2012 where the default is to use 4.5, while it can easily target 2.0. But that's up to OP to say. :)

Comment: Yes, that's what it is. I rebuilt it targeting 4.0, and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install the .NET Framework. You can't include it "in a dll or something".

Comment: My life would be so much easier if I could though.

Comment: OP could create an installer for his console app that detects if the target version of the framework is not installed and prompt to install it, but that's probably as close as he could get to including it "in a dll or something"

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: ??? He would still need to install it on the server. And in fact the console application already tells him to install it.

Comment: IIRC you can configure an installer to install dependencies for you, including the .NET framework. Thus, the installer that installs the console app would also install the target version of the framework if it is not already installed. I'm imagining the scenario in which OP has to install the console app on multiple machines. It's obviously not worth it for only one install.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: Still: The .NET framework would need to be installed on the server - *no matter how*

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: But that was, what the OP was asking :-)

Comment: I suppose I was trying to pander to OP's laziness :)

Answer (score 2):

> **Yes**, you must install .Net Framework on your machine where you want to
>   run your developed application.

Check this [How to create a Setup package by using Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353), just include your project output and the .Net Framework as prerequisites.

Just `.Net Framework` and your console application output exe or .dll that you have created.
.Net Framework setup automatically install all thing/ environment to run your application on Server.

@Mark made good point that you can target a version of the framework which your server operating system include by default. Check that [**What version of the .NET Framework is included in which version of the OS**?](http://www.msigeek.com/2390/what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-which-version-of-the-os) and select the appropriate version of target framework and then you need not to install .Net Framework on your Server

Reference:
[Visual Studio Windows Application Setup Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12548/Visual-Studio-Windows-Application-Setup-Project)
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164495/windows-7-default-net-framework